# Minimization problem of parametric equations in ballistics (minimum projectile speed)

Tags: calculus, optimization, kinematics, projectile-motion

I am trying to solve a minimization problem for a physics simulation in Unity 3D. In short, a projectile is fired at a certain position with a certain velocity, and experiences a constant acceleration (in the 3 axis directions) due to gravity/wind. I want the projectile to hit a moving target with any amount of time derivatives of position (acceleration, jerk, snap, crackle, etc.).

By expanding the initial condition differential equations, we can use a Taylor expansion to model the trajectories of both objects (that is the method I am using, [someone on Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775218/ballistics-solution-works-for-acceleration-but-seemingly-not-higher-derivatives) questioned it as if it were bad? If someone has a better solution, please offer suggestions). Therefore, by letting all the variables be the initial conditions at time $0$, here are the kinematic equations:

Projectile: $$x_p(t) = x_p+v_p t + \frac{1}{2}a_p t^2$$
($v_p$ is the unknown we are searching for.)

Target: $$x_t(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^{(k)}_t t^k}{k!}$$

As I mentioned, the variables without an input parameter are initial conditions with $t = 0$. The movement conditions are all 3D vectors, while time is a scalar parameter.
We want the 2 objects to intersect, so we impose the equation

$$x_p(t) = x_t(t)$$
$$x_p+v_p t + \frac{1}{2}a_p t^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^{(k)}t^k}{k!}$$

At this stage I am unsure how to proceed. We are trying to minimize the projectile speed for given initial conditions: therefore, I tried a few different things.

When setting up an Euler-Lagrange equation with $L(t,\dot{x}, \ddot{x})$, everything cancelled out to $0=0$, no useful result.

Also, I had tried to compare coefficients of the polynomials in a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749274/solution-works-for-2nd-degree-polynomial-but-does-not-extend-to-higher-degrees), but that solution didn't seem to work. If anyone could explain why, that would be appreciated.

Is there a fast numerical solution, or perhaps an alternative, more clever analytical solution to this problem?

Comment: $v_p$ is not a constant?

Comment: No, $v_p$ is unknown since I am trying to figure out the minimum bullet speed. Because of this, the travel time to intersection is also unknown.

Comment: Wikipedia has a fairly long article on numerical differentiation, including a section that describes a [stable algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Complex-variable_methods) in the holomorphic case. I admit that I find your overall question a bit confusing, particularly regarding the target's motion in the axis orthogonal to the projectile's plane of motion. But I will think on it further.

Comment: Sorry if it appears confusing, do you have any suggestions on where to clarify things? The target can move in all 3 axes, so I am not sure what you are meaning by that. Its position derivatives are 3D vectors. By the way, after looking at the Wikipedia page, I see you linked to the complex case, but I am only looking for real solutions for the speed, obviously.

Comment: And so I am not sure how the complex computations will affect the performance. This problem can be solved pretty easily using numerical bracketing methods, but it is extremely slow and cannot run in real-time. I am trying to find something that will work fast enough to run on many different target objects in an instant. That way it will avoid mismatches due to lag or calculation delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) Since the unknown vector $\vec v_p $ satisfies an equation of the form  $\vec  v_p t = \sum_{k=0}^n \vec c_k t^k$  in which each $\vec c_k$ is a known constant vector, you can write  $\vec v_p = t^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^n \vec c_k t^k$. Denote the right-hand side as $\vec R(t)$ and treat it as a known parametrized particle path in 3-space.

(ii) Your goal is to find the value of $t>0$ that minimizes the squared length $L^2 = ||\vec R(t)||^2$. If you visualize the trajectory traced by $\vec R(t)$ as a smooth space curve, then it is clear that $L$ is the radius of a  sphere centered at the origin that can be drawn tangent to this curve. Imagine temporarily that the space curve is parametrized by its arclength. Then at the critical time where the curve contacts this critical sphere, the velocity vector $\vec T= \vec R'$ is perpendicular to the radius vector $\vec R$. This scalar equation $\vec R \cdot \vec R'=0$ can be solved for the unknown scalar $t$.  Thus you now know the critical value of $\vec R$ and of $L$ which is a candidate for the absolute minimum.

(iii) Thus we have reduced the problem to solving a single scalar equation, and that equation (after a bit of massaging) can be re-written as a polynomial in $t$. Newton's method is the standard numerical algorithm for solving such polynomial equations when the degree exceeds two. Or you may have access to a built-in root-solver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how the velocity vector $\vec R'$ is necessarily perpendicular to the radius vector? I am not sure I understand, would it be possible to maybe add drawings to visualize things?

Comment: Also, if $\vec R$ and $\vec R'$ are perpendicular, then why is $\vec R''$ needed? Wouldn't $\vec R \cdot \vec R'' = 0$ be simpler to compute?
As for the equation, as long as the right hand side is $0$, I have an implementation of the ITP rootfinder, so I just have to write code to evaluate the left-hand side function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the velocity vector is perpendicular to the radius because it should be tangent to the surface? But I still don't understand why the normal acceleration vector is needed.

Comment: You are correct about $R''$ and the triple product, so I edited the answer accordingly. The second derivative $R''$ would only be needed if you wanted to check that the critical point is a true minimum via the second derivative test.

Comment: I have managed to implement it in Unity to work correctly. I had to try out a lot of tweaking for the rootfinder, it seems like there are multiple critical points for this function. However if I iterate it for the number of possible solutions (order of the highest derivative), then it works properly. Thanks!